# Kafka retry property not working as expected

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have setup up Kafka using version 2.8.1 with the basic configuration as 1 Broker 1 Topic and 1 Partition.
I use the following code to send

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    //1. Create producer configuration information
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:19092");
    properties.put("max.block.ms","5000");
    properties.put("retries","3");
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    //2. Create producer object
    KafkaProducer<String,String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
   
    //3. Send data
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test","CallBack--1"), new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
                if (exception == null){
                    System.out.println(metadata.partition()+"=="+metadata.offset());
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Error!!!");
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    countDownLatch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    //4. Close resources
    producer.close();
}
```

Both my Broker & Zookeeper are down and I expect `Error!!` to appear in the log 3 times, but nothing happens after the error `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 5000 ms`.How can I set up repeats when the broker is unavailable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to write your own loop to do this. The TCP request will fail to connect if the broker is down. The config `retries` for a producer is for handling *transient* errors, on sending data itself, not establishing broker connections.

Also, note that `2147483647` is the default retries value, so there is no reason to explicitly set it to a lower value in this case.